# MySQL / MariaDB Strict Mode

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was developing some code using MySQL as a DB, with various indexes.  I had MySQL running in strict mode.

As an experiment, I switched to MariaDB (also in strict mode) and found that many of indexes were failing because they were too long (above 767 bytes).  If I remove Strict mode in MariaDB, the indexes *seem* to be created.

My question is: are those indexes actually being created, even though they are clearly too large?

If not, how do I deal with indexing VARCHAR strings?

Comment: This question should be migrated to the dba site of SE

Comment: What `CHARACTER SET` was used in MySQL?  In MariaDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MYSQL, after index creation you can see that messages using `SHOW WARNINGS` in the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Strict mode is playing its role when you pass the incomplete values to database from front end design in any markup or front end development  language.

If you are using local servers like Wamp or Xamp then simply goes to 
localhost/phpmyadmin

simply login to your database system and then goes to "variables" which is in the top navigation bar.

Just search there "SQL Mode" as there are lots of variables so you need to search or you may traverse there for "SQL Mode".

Now after you  search, you will find a line has name SQL mode and at its left side Edit button is there. Click on "Edit". It will simply open the line of variables which are in strict mode by default by MariaDB or Mysql, whatever it may be.

Just remove the keyword "Strict" from this line and again goes to Edit button where you can see the "Save" button.

Now the strict mode is removed from your database server.